# Save each box height and assign it on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of boxes and I save each height like that:

```
$(function(){

     $(".box").each(function(){
         boxSize = $(this).height();
     });
```

Then I call it like this:

```
      button.click(function(){
         $(".box").height(boxSize);
      });
});
```

But it doesn't, i would like boxSize to be specific for each box, anyone?

Thanks

Comment: you want to assign the height of box itself on its own click?

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing enough of your code to come up with an answer, but a couple of things jump out at me.<br>1. What kind of element is it and why would it's height change anyway?<br>2. Is button already a jQuery object?  If not, then it needs to be $(button).click(...<br>3. That function will set all of the elements with the `box` class to the same height.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's hard to offer you help when your question is so broad! Why do you need to set the box height?

Comment: @user1018804 still no clue what you want to do.  The box elements are all positioned absolutely, left:0, top:58px, then moved using a CSS3 transform to another location.  When I click on any of the filters other than "all", all of the box elements are scaled to .001 and set opacity to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".box").each(function(){
         boxSize = $(this).height();
     });
```

this function always sets the last elements height to boxSize variable. You should array variable for save the all elements height value.

Answer (score 1):

you variable boxSize is not visible in your click function, thus you cannot retrieve the value. Check it out by logging the varibles to console in both functions.

Comment: $(function(){

      button.click(function(){
          $(".box").each(function(){
              boxSize = $(this).height();
          });
          $(".box").height(boxSize);
      });
});

This way?

Comment: have you understood the question?

Comment: @Christoph it's hard to say that because we don't see anything outside of where the variable is defined and there's no `var` keyword.  `boxSize` could actually be defined in the global scope.

Comment: yah, it is defined in the global space without var, my bad. But he will always override the height with the value of the last element of bis `.box`-array, so it just won't work.

Comment: provided a better comment and a live link above. i'm thinking to push values to an array tho

Comment: Where do i put that? 
I was actually thinking of using this:

list = [];
boxHeight = $(".box").height();
    $(".box").each(data, function(){
        list.push(boxHeight);
    });


But how do i call th array then on a click?

Comment: `$.data()` lets you put data directly to a jquery object, in your case you can store the height for each of your boxes.
Check out http://api.jquery.com/data/ and see, if you can figure it out;)
Hint: `$(this).data("height",$(this).height())`